# A better way to perform grouped aggregation and sorting with pandas

Tags: python, performance, pandas, dataframe, optimization

I'm using the babies' name data source. The data is something like this

```
name   sex births year
Mary    F  7065   1880
Anna    F  2604   1880
Emma    F  2003   1880
...
Zariyan M   5     2016
Zarren  M   5     2016
Zaryn   M   5     2016
```

The aim is to filter out and get only year 2011 and beyond. Then, aggregating the duplicates, grouping by sex and sorting in descending order. The output is this.

```
sex name      births
F   Emma      121375
F   Sophia    117352
F   Olivia    111691
F   Isabella  103947
F   Ava        94507
M   Noah      110280
M   Mason     105104
M   Jacob     104722
M   Liam      103250
M   William    99144
```

I manage to do this but my code is really inefficient and tedious. There should be a better way of doing this but I don't know how. Here's my code.

```
bnames_2010 = bnames.loc[bnames['year'] > 2010]

a = bnames_2010.groupby(['sex', 'name'], sort=False)['births'].sum().reset_index()

b = a.sort(['sex', 'births'], ascending=False)

c = b.groupby('sex').head()

bnames_top5 = c.sort('sex')
print('bnames_top5')
```

Comment: I believe your post is more appropriate for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @diegoperini I doubt Code Review has enough pandas experts to judge the appropriateness of this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're sorting too many times. Additionally, the `groupby` *also* performs a sort, invalidating your previous sorting. Here's how I'd do it -

```
df = df.query("year >= 2011")\                   
       .groupby(['name', 'sex'], sort=False, as_index=False))\    
       .births.sum()\                              
       .sort_values(['sex', 'births'], ascending=[True, False])
       .groupby('sex', sort=False)\
       .head(5)\
```

1. `query` filters on `year`
2. `groupby` will group by `name` and `sex`, and will prevent the result from being sorted
3. `sum` will sum `birth` by group
4. `sort_values` will sort the result in ascending order of `sex` and descending order of births.
5. Another `groupby` + `head` call retrieves the top 5 rows by `sex` (optional)

Comment: This is great. Thanks. But, how do I get the top 5 for male and female in one dataframe like the one I posted? Here's my way I just did.       df.groupby('sex').head()

Comment: @WilsonLiao Take a look at it now?

Comment: @WilsonLiao You're welcome! I invite you to do a timings comparison between your current code and this, to see how they fare performance wise.